# Replace value Loop PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel

Hi im starting with PHPExcel and i would like to make a loop to search values on all cells and replace the current value by a new one , im stucked right now i don't how to do that

Would like to change "MT201501" to "MT205481"

Thanks for your help

```
    <?php
        require_once 'C:/wamp/www/Stage/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Chargement du fichier Excel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("HES.xlsx");

/**
* récupération de la première feuille du fichier Excel
* @var PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet
*/
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

echo '<table border="1">';

// On boucle sur les lignes





foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {



   echo '<tr>';

   // On boucle sur les cellule de la ligne
   foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
      echo '<td>';
      print_r($cell->getValue());
      echo '</td>';
   }

   echo '</tr>';
}


echo '</table>';





    ?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Is it displaying the contents of the cells? Your code doesn't show any checking of the value in the cell to see if it's "MT201501", are you having problems writing an `if` to compare the values? Are you having problems figuring out how to set a cell value to "MT205481"? Are you have problems saving the updated spreadsheet to file?

Comment: I just have problem to do the IF on PHPExcel i know i have to put it inside the loop but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Rather than use `print_r($cell->getValue());` do your comparison: `if ($cell->getValue() === 'MT201501') { $cell->setValue('MT205481'); }` and then save the file when you've finished updating